# How to kill all specific java processes

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have following search result coming from netstat:

```
netstat -nap | grep java | grep :::300*
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp6       0      0 :::30008                :::*                    LISTEN      81159/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::30010                :::*                    LISTEN      81164/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::30001                :::*                    LISTEN      81155/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::30002                :::*                    LISTEN      81162/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::30003                :::*                    LISTEN      81156/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::30004                :::*                    LISTEN      81161/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::30005                :::*                    LISTEN      81158/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::30006                :::*                    LISTEN      81157/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::30007                :::*                    LISTEN      81160/java
```

now I need to iterate over that result, get the process id ad kill it. How can I do it ?

Comment: Note that _in general_, needing to do this at all in the first place means you're doing something wrong (or at least, not following modern process-supervision practices). If you're using systemd services to run your Java processes, f/e, they're all in a cgroup, so terminating that cgroup (as performed by `systemctl stop`, unless the service is configured to have a different shutdown mechanism) shuts them all down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PIDS=( $(netstat -nap | grep java | grep :::300*| awk '{print $6}' | cut -d/ -f2 | xargs) ); for p in "${PIDS[@]}"; do kill -9 ${p}; done`
i think you can do like this but i think can be more easy way

Comment: I have this erro when run: cut: the delimiter must be a single character

Comment: sorry
change please `cut -d "\/" -f2` to `cut -d/ -f2`

Comment: Yes, sure,  
it can be not array and not in loop -  
something like this: 
`kill -9 $(netstat -nap | grep java | grep :::300*| awk '{print $6}' | cut -d/ -f2 | xargs)`

Comment: You can pass more than one PID on `kill`'s command line at a time; no reason to loop. And awk can do the work of grep _and also_ the work you're using `cut` for -- you could run `kill -9 $(netstat -nap | awk '/java/ && /:::300/ { gsub(/\/.*$/, "", $6); print $6 }')` f/e

Comment: ...and btw, `array=( $(anything) )` is an antipattern -- see [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29).

Comment: Also, going straight to `kill -9` is often a Very Bad Idea; it doesn't let a program flush its buffers and clean up properly, so at minimum, logs in the interval just prior to the SIGKILL are liable not to be flushed; if this Java program is something like a database server, `kill -9` is putting you at high risk for data corruption.

Comment: @rkrankus, ...btw, what's the purpose of the `xargs` on the end of that pipeline? With no arguments, it's going to perform vaguely shell-like word-splitting, but the shell itself does shell-like wordsplitting, and does it _better_.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, you're right

Comment: I think it's nearly there. rkrankus and Charles Duffy, your scripts work but both return this error:  bash: kill: LISTEN: arguments must be process or job IDs

Comment: I don't fully understand command but it returns LISTEN rather than pid number, it looks better when I change $6 to $7, it returns last column: 122141/java 122145/java. Thing is now to cut /java from it I think

Comment: this is it:  kill -9 $(netstat -nap | awk '/java/ && /:::300/ { gsub(/\/.*$/, "", $7); print $7 }')

Comment: actually I dropped -9 flag as suggested above, it is better indeed

Answer (score 0):

It's not good code, but the following does what you asked for (newlines added for clarity, would be equally correct without them):

```
kill $(netstat -nap | awk '
  /java/ && /:::300[[:digit:]]{2}/ {
    gsub(/\/.*$/, "", $6);
    gsub(/[^[:digit:]], "", $6);
    print $6
  }
')
```

The second `gsub` is a safety measure, to ensure that only digits are printed; this reduces the chances of shell globbing or string splitting having unintended effects should the column ordering be off.

---

Consider using systemd or another process supervision framework to manage services, instead of doing this kind of thing with hand-written code.